# VB.NET validate the form to check if empty fields or errors exists

Tags: vb.net, validation, error-handling

So far I have written code to remain Save&Update buttons disabled until user fills all required fields(Textboxes & Comboboxes) in Groupbox, but I also want the Save&Update buttons to remain disabled until user has addressed all errors available in the form e.g Book_Name should not go beyond 50 characters!

I would really appreciate if someone help me in this!

Below is the code that I tried to do so what I have mentioned above but somehow it is not working:

```
Private Sub ValidateInputs(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim strErrorList As String
    strErrorList = ""
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If Len(ErrorProvider1.GetError(ctrl)) > 0 Then
            strErrorList += ErrorProvider1.GetError(ctrl) & ChrW(10) &
            ChrW(13)
        End If
    Next

    If Len(strErrorList) = 0 Then
        ' Process stuff if no errors
        btnsave.Enabled = Not GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).Any(Function(t) t.Text = String.Empty) And _
       Not (cboStaff_id.Text = String.Empty OrElse cboPub_id.Text = String.Empty OrElse cboSub_Code.Text = String.Empty _
            OrElse DateTimePicker1.Text = " ")

        btnSaveUpdate.Enabled = Not GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox).Any(Function(cbo) cbo.Text = String.Empty) And _
            Not (txtbook_name.Text = String.Empty OrElse txtauthor.Text = String.Empty OrElse txtprice.Text = String.Empty _
                 OrElse txtrack_no.Text = String.Empty OrElse TxtNo_of_Books.Text = String.Empty OrElse txtvol_no.Text = String.Empty OrElse DateTimePicker1.Text = " ")
        btndelete.Enabled = Not (cboISBN.Text = String.Empty)
    Else
        btnsave.Enabled = False
        btnSaveUpdate.Enabled = False
        MessageBox.Show(strErrorList, "List Of Errors")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why cant you add a test for `TBISBN.Text.Length < 13` to that?

Comment: @Plutonix I have control over all fields textchanged event and in case value doesn't match the required regex pattern the errorprovider will appear. What I want now is that save/update button remain disabled until all errors are corrected!

Comment: I understood the question.

Comment: So @Plutonix can you provide an answer then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I asked the question 4 days ago and no one provided an answer to solve my problem, I researched & rechecked my code and found solution for my problem!

So I am gonna explain each point to clarify what I have done.

```
'Below disables numeric entry; only characters and spaces allowed with the help of ASCII values
Private Sub txtbook_name_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtbook_name.KeyPress
    If Not (Asc(e.KeyChar) = 8) Then
        If Not ((Asc(e.KeyChar) >= 97 And Asc(e.KeyChar) <= 122) _  Or (Asc(e.KeyChar) >= 65 _
                                                                    And Asc(e.KeyChar) <= 90) _
                                                               Or (Asc(e.KeyChar) = 32)) Then
            e.KeyChar = ChrW(0)
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
'Bellow function return only true if input matches Regex pattern in other cases false
 Private Function ValidBook_name(ByVal book_name As String, ByRef errorMessage As String) As Boolean
    Dim regex As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^[a-zA-Z ]{1,50}$")
    ' Confirm there is text in the control.
    If txtbook_name.Text.Length = 0 Then
        errorMessage = "Book Name is required"
        Return False
    End If
    If txtbook_name.Text.Length > 50 Then
        errorMessage = "Book Name can not be more than 50"
        Return False
    End If
    'Confirm that book name is in character not number
    If (regex.IsMatch(Trim(txtbook_name.Text))) Then
        errorMessage = ""
        Return True
    End If
    errorMessage = "A valid Book Name is required" + ControlChars.Cr
    Return False
End Function
'Check whether input entered is valid or not; if not return cursor to control 
 Private Sub txtbook_name_Validating(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles txtbook_name.Validating
    Dim errorMsg As String
    Try
            If Not ValidBook_name(txtbook_name.Text, errorMsg) Then
                ' Cancel the event and select the text to be corrected by the user.
                e.Cancel = True
                txtbook_name.Select(0, txtbook_name.Text.Length)
                ' Set the ErrorProvider error with the text to display. 
                Me.ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtbook_name, errorMsg)
            End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub txtbook_name_Validated(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtbook_name.Validated
    ' If all conditions have been met, clear the error provider of errors.
    Try
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(txtbook_name, "")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Use Error Providers Or Create your own error provider that does the task required for you and for the ISBN textBox say put the MaxLength=13 it will do the task without any error providers or validators, For phone number of email use masked text box, or handle the text change event of the textbox if you want to accept only numbers in that textbox

Comment: I have control over all fields textchanged event and in case value doesn't match the required regex pattern the errorprovider will appear. What I want now is that save/update button remain disabled until all errors are corrected!

Comment: make a invisible textbox in the form put y when all errors are corrected and no more errors and put y if there is an error , in the text change event of the new textbox write if else to enable or disable save/update.

Comment: didn't get what you meant?